# Algorithm: Where to place the facility, digging the well, to have minimal distance in total

Tags: algorithm, tree, shortest-path

The question is: You are appointed by a Non-governmental Organization whose mission is to increase access to drinkable water to find the optimal place to dig a well in a village. The sum of the distances to the houses should be minimal, but there are obstacles (walls, cliffs, trees) in the way.
An example would be:

[image: example map]

Where # is an obstacle and * is a house.

What I have tried:
1) for each empty grid, run a Breadth-first search algorithm. and calculate the total distance from that grid to all the houses. Finally, find the one that has the smallest distance.

2) build a complete graph for this map. i.e., connect all the possible routes.
Finally, run the Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm for it. All the empty grid locate on the MST is the solutions

Comment: Preform a flood algorithm on the set where every cell is an obstacle or house or if its not it is the minimum of the surrounding cells +1

Comment: Great point! but does MST work?

Comment: maybe, I dont see how a graph algorithm is directly applicable to this problem (seems more like a DP one to me) but maybe if you represent it in a certain way MST would work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of houses is small, you can run BFS from each house instead of from each empty cell, then take the cell with the minimum sum of distances.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is over-engineering.

The objective function need not be the “sum” : what if there is an outlier that contributes heavily ?

Also the solutions you have tried are flawed : breadth-first search and MST apply to tree topology which is not existing in your problem setup.

Why don't you do a geographic centre of gravity calculation ; find this initial point ; then apply perturbation techniques to refine the solution ?

Comment: I don't understand why you're arguing the objective function is bad. I assumed this was a puzzle, not a real-world scenario. Also BFS and MST most certainly apply to graphs, and BFS at least solves this problem.

Comment: It's the question from Google, and they said it more likes a NP-complete...